# Подбросить и подОбрать - почему разные варианты приставки?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Почему иногда в глаголах бывает "под" (подбежать), а иногда "подо" (подойти)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря помощи [[@tmp](/users/1170/tmp)](/users/1170/tmp) мы получили правила из словаря Кузнецова и словря Ушакова, и теперь можем рассмотреть вопрос подробнее.

[КУЗНЕЦОВ](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%EF%EE%E4): ПОДО... (перед односложными корнями: подобреть, подогрев, подоспеть; перед некоторыми группами согласных: подопрелый, подостлать, подоткнуть)

[УШАКОВ](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/946778): ПОДО…, глагольная приставка. То же, что под…1. употр.: 1) перед согласной, за которой следует ь, напр. подошью, подобью, подовью; 2) перед й, напр. подойду; 3) в некоторых случаях перед группой согласных, напр. подогнуть, подослать, подобрать

---

Проверяем гипотезу "Перед односложными корнями". Навскидку, без словаря, сразу можно извлечь из головы: поддать, поддеть, поднять, подлезть... По-моему, не выдерживает критики.

Гипотеза "Перед *некоторыми* группами согласных" ("*В некоторых случаях* перед группами согласных") сама по себе очень слаба, практически, ни о чём.

А вот мягкий знак и *й* наводят на интересные мысли. О чередовании. Подобью - подбить, подошью - подшить. Сюда же вполне вписываются и "группы согласных": подобрать - подберу, подослать - подсылать. Новую гипотезу я бы сформулировал так:

**если в корне глагола есть беглая гласная, то при её нулевой реализации приставка будет иметь форму ПОДО**

Этой гипотезе противоречат примеры Кузнецова: *подогреть*, *подоспеть* (в *подобреть*, думаю, всё-таки приставка *по*). Ну, есть, конечно, подозрение, что в противоречащих примерах беглая гласная когда-то была. Но всё равно вопрос пока остаётся для меня открытым.

---

**UPD**. Порывшись в словарях (тех, что были под рукой), обнаружил всего-то 22 корня, перед которыми приставка при нулевой беглой гласной принимает форму ПОДО:

-лест(ь), -ход-, -бер-, -би(ть), -гон-, -гиб-, -дер-, -жиг-, -жид-, -жим-, -жин-, -зыв-, -ли(ть), -мин-, -пер-, -пи(ть), -рыв-, -сыл-, -стил-, -тык-, -тир-, -ши(ть)

И 4 исключения, не вписывающихся в мою гипотезу:

-гре(ть), -двиг-, -пре(ть), (у)спе(ть)

Вот полный список найденных слов (словоформ) из словарей (Е - Ефремова, ОШ - Ожегов, У - Ушаков): [podo_words.htm](http://ir2.ru/podo_words.htm) (повезло, что в словаре Ушакова почему-то есть формы *ПОДОШЁЛ*).

Нашёл подтверждение "исключительности" своих четырёх (и других!) слов (**Русская грамматика**, Словообразование, § 853):

> В некоторых глаголах наличие фонемы
> |о| не обусловлено правилами и
> закреплено лексически: обозначить,
> обознаться, обокрасть, отодвинуть,
> пододвинуть, разогреть, разонравиться
> (разг.), соблюсти, соблаговолить
> (устар. и ирон.), согреть, согрешить,
> сокрушить, соприкоснуться, сотрясти,
> сохранить.

Там же (§ 851) полный список приставок с факультативной фонемой |о| на конце: в-/во-, вз-/взо-, воз-/возо-, из-/изо-, над-/надо-, низ-/низо-, об-/обо-, om-/omo-, под-/подо-, пред-/предо-, раз-/разо-, с-/co.

Comment: >>Этой гипотезе противоречат примеры Кузнецова: подогреть, подоспеть (в подобреть, думаю, всё-таки приставка по). Ну, есть, конечно, подозрение, что в противоречащих примерах беглая гласная когда-то была.

 В первом случае точно была, мне думается. Все же связь между "гореть"/"греть" есть.

Answer (score 1):

Это два варианта одной приставки. Выбирается благозвучный вариант, хотя существует правило. Вы же не скажете "ПОДОбежать" или "ПОДйти"?

Comment: DocentI, простите увидел крест - и случайно удалил Ваш комментарий.

Comment: Да ради бога. Я так, беседую

Answer (score 0):

Перед односложными глаголами (т.е. корнями, кроме иноязычных) и перед некоторыми скоплениями труднопроизносимых согласных - подо. В подобных случаях "под" как правило невозможно. Во всех остальных - регулярно "под".

Среди очень редких исключений - "подо" как сочетание двух приставок "по" и "до".

Comment: подбрить, подобрать. И согласные те же,и количество слогов.

Comment: Ларf, у меня нет оснований отстаивать утверждение, которого я не говорил.
PS А в брить - Р мягкий.

Comment: behemothus, пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на [более-менее] авторитетный источник или приведите прямо здесь достаточное для подтверждения вашего тезиса количество примеров.

Comment: grumant, сформулируйте, пожалуйста, утверждение, о котором вы говорите.

Comment: Как не говорили? Прочитайте начало Вашего ответа, правда, оно с ошибками, может, я что-то не поняла?

Comment: Простите, Ларf, я вот тоже не понял, о чем Вы.
Да. Говорил, что в 
Про одинаковость корней не говорил ничего.
Ошибку поправил, спасибо.

Comment: Не будьте мнительны. И я в той теме не обижалась.(Хотя я человек очень обидчивый).  Просто формальных доказательств для того, что союз у Есенина может быть присоединительный - я вам не назову. Такой ответ Вам не понравится. Поэтому и промолчала.

Comment: @behemothus, вы, в частности, писали: "Да. Говорил, что перед односложными глагольными корнями обычно - подо". Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на первоисточник или привести необходимое для подтверждения этого тезиса количество примеров?

Answer (score 0):

**stopkran**

Бегемотус Вам более ничего не даст.
Но от его имени могу посоветовать посмотреть в словарь Кузнецова.

**Ларf**

> Просто формальных доказательств для того, что союз у Есенина может быть присоединительный - я вам не назову.

Разве Бегемотус просил от Вас каких-то доказательств?! У Вас был с ним совсем о другом.

А вот Ваш вопрос мне тоже непонятен. Не могли бы как-то по-другому его задать или более полно?

> Да ради бога. Я так, беседую

**DocentlI**,

Да, лихие у Вас беседы. )))

Вам grumant привет передает с меты. Предлагает продожить общение с Бегемотусом, а у него теперь нет ни возможности, ни желания. Больно уж дорого обходится.

**stopkran**
Вы уверены, что правильно сформулировали "гипотезу" из Кузнецова? Я - нет. 
Кузнецов автор весьма двусмысленный вообще, но в данном случае Ваша версия трактовки "гипотезы" опровергается её же автором, точнее - примерами. Посмотрите, ничего глаз не режет? Помимо сказанного?

А вообще, коли Вы на меня сслыаетесь, совет позволите?
Если Вы действительно озаботились решеним этой проблемы, то не занимайтесь ерундой. "Прверять" подобные вещи, как бы они не были сформулированы, можно только ставя во главу угла всю историю падения редуцированных, ибо -О на конце - это рефлекс ера (Ъ). Смотрите, где он был в сильных позициях - там сейчас О. Поскольку все односложные корни с двумя и более согласными в начле исторически были двусложными, значит надо смотреть, на какой слог из этих двух корневых слогов падало ударение. Если оно смещалось на первый, ныне пропавший слог, то вернее всего там может быть "подо-". Это даже не гипотеза, проект оной. Но все ж больше толку чем в пустом поиске опревергающих примеров на чкобы кузнецовскую трагтовку.

И ещё. Есть как минимум один безусловный пример возможности ипользования обоих вариантов (c тем же значением): подпреть и подопреть. Это напрочь опровергает идею предопределенности, т.е. какой-либо примитивной проверки на примерах, только статистическая. Кстати, именно так, имхо, надо и Кузнецова понимать. "**В некоторых случаях** при односложных корнях и перед скоплениями согласных...".

Забыл. Поведение Под-подо, очень похоже на О-обо. Там, где "подо" - почти всегда "обо".
Подобрать - обобрать, подогреть-обогреть (огреть - это уже другой смысл), подогнать-обогнать и проч. Т.е. механизм ти решения должны быть те же. Но на О-Обо гораздо больше примеров, разобраться будет проще.

Да, еще то же самое с От-Ото, В-ВО (вбирать-вобрать, подбьирать-подобрать) с-со (с некоторыми исключениями). Короче, надо искать общую закономерность для большинства таких приставок. Да еще не забыть вличние церковнославянского неполногласия...

Comment: @tmp, у меня нет словаря Кузнецова. Не могли бы вы дать ссылку на интернет-ресурс? Или хотя бы уточнить, о чём этот словарь (я сам поищу по теме). Я нахожу в Яндексе только толковый словарь Кузнецова - но мне кажется, что это не то, о чём вы говорили: там ведь не описываются закономерности морфонологии?..

Comment: Это именно он. Большой Толковый Словарь. На грамоте есть.
http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%EF%EE%E4

Только не заставляйте меня оправдываться за его некорректности в формулировках. Я их вижу. И я постарался сформулировать эьто нормально.

Comment: нет, у меня нет претензий к его формулировкам. Просто потому что я вообще не могу найти там ни одной формулировки по теме. 

Вы не могли бы дать более точную ссылку на страницу, где в этом словаре сформулированы (пусть и не очень корректно) правила реализации ПОД/ПОДО или других приставок с похожим чередованием (не связанные со смыслоразличением)?

Comment: >Просто потому что я вообще не могу найти там ни одной формулировки по теме. 
Я вам дал ссылку. Могу еще процитировать.

_**ПОД...; ПОДО... (перед односложными корнями: подобреть, подогрев, подоспеть; перед некоторыми группами согласных: подопрелый, подостлать, подоткнуть);**_

Comment: Спасибо! Чёрт, я ссылку-то не посмотрел, подумал, она на "вообще" словарь...

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за "список приставок с факультативной фонемой |о| на конце".

Я не лингвист - программист... Взбрело в голову написать [программу проверки стихотворного ритма](http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe) Там словарь нужен, и пришлось пользоваться допотопной бесплатной электронной формой словаря Зализняка с кучей ошибок. Увы, вряд ли у меня сейчас достанет времени и настойчивости получить нормальное лингвистическое образование, чтобы правильно выполнить постановку задания и кодирование орфоэпического словаря с нуля. Остаётся единственный путь - и дальше "стоять на плечах гигантов".  Я использую материал, [собранный и оформленный группой С.А. Старостина](http://starling.rinet.ru/downl.php?lan=ru#dict) Но развитие этого проекта застопорилось со смертью лидера... Сейчас руки дошли до группы глаголов с этими приставками. Для однокоренных глаголов "о" влазит везде, где нет гласной в конце приставки.

Comment: @Tom d_Cat, как программист программисту: вам понадобится гораздо более длинный список. Ключевое слово здесь - _мофонология_, единственная более-менее полная книга об этом явлении - **Чурганова В. Г. Очерк русской морфонологии** (может быть, уже даже есть где-нибудь в DJVU).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Извиняюсь перед Вами и Администрацией сайта - я ещё не освоился с местными правилами, и поэтому подправил основной ответ.

Программа уже живая, и сейчас я латаю базу данных в меру своего понимания.

Интересно, существуют на просторах интернета качественные бесплатные базы орфоэпического словаря для русского (а может, и украинского) языка?

Comment: Нет. В течение последних лет пяти я периодически ищу в сети словарь Аванесова, но нигде не могу найти - ни для скачивания, ни онлайн. А все остальные словари ненадёжны.

Comment: >Я не лингвист - программист...    
   
Я тоже. Правда сейчас - на незаслуженном отдыхе.    
  
>подправил основной ответ.  
  
Свой? Нет проблем. Имеете право.  

>ищу в сети словарь Аванесова,  
http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0021.htm  
 
Кстати, Tom d_Cat, а вы на старлинге работаете как член команды или  просто его пользуете? 
И вообще, если есть какая нужда насчет помощи с прграммированием подобных вещей, отпишите мне, модет пригожусь. 
Мыло тут
http://russ.hashcode.ru/users/445/behemothus

Comment: Не, я "хичник-одиночка". ;)

Касательно помощи...
Сейчас у меня идея-фикс - вот это: http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe
Если скачаете мою программу и попинаете за что-то конкретное - буду благодарен.
Только не пинайте за встроенный орфоэпический словарь  - с упомянутым Вами Аванесовым это и близко не лежало.

Comment: Из меня тестировщик никудушный. 
Тем более, что мне сама идея такой программы кажется за уши притянутой.
Ну хорошо, коли сам напросился - попробую. Если будет, что сказать, нашишу на мыло.

Comment: Это смотря чего от программы хотеть.  
Собственно, у неё и нет никакой особой идеи. Всё было придумано до меня - осталось только реализовать и подобрать материал.  
Русская версия, как по мне, довольно-таки сносно делает то, что хотел от неё я. А на днях обнаружил чудесные бесплатные украинские словари - http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/LSlist/ - и онлайн и устанавливаемые.